# HAProxy with Kubernetes in a DR setup

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy

We have Kubernetes setup hosted on premises and are trying to allow clients outside of K8s to connect to services hosted in the K8s cluster.

In order to make this work using HA Proxy (which runs outside K8s), we have the HAProxy backend configuration as follows -

```
   backend vault-backend
   ...
   ...
   server k8s-worker-1 worker1:32200 check
   server k8s-worker-2 worker2:32200 check
   server k8s-worker-3 worker3:32200 check
```

Now, this solution works, but the worker names and the corresponding nodePorts are hard-coded in this config, which obviously is inconvenient as and when more workers are added (or removed/changed).

We came across the HAProxy Ingress Controller (https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy_ingress_controller_for_kubernetes/) which sounds promising, but (we feel) effectively adds another HAProxy layer to the mix..and thus, adds another failure point.

Is there a better solution to implement this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

> Now, this solution works, but the worker names and the corresponding nodePorts are hard-coded in this config, which obviously is inconvenient as and when more workers are added (or removed/changed).

You can explicitly configure the NodePort for your Kubernetes [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) so it doesn't pick a random port and you always use the same port on your external HAProxy:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: <my-nodeport-service>
  labels:
    <my-label-key>: <my-label-value>
spec:
  selector:
    <my-selector-key>: <my-selector-value>
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - port: <service-port>
     nodePort: 32200
```

> We came across the HAProxy Ingress Controller (https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy_ingress_controller_for_kubernetes/) which sounds promising, but (we feel) effectively adds another HAProxy layer to the mix..and thus, adds another failure point.

You could run the HAProxy ingress inside the cluster and remove the HAproxy outside the cluster, but this really depends on what type of service you are running. The Kubernetes [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) is Layer 7 resource, for example. The DR here would be handled by having multiple replicas of your HAProxy ingress controller.

Comment: Thanks Rico, for the quick response. You are right -  configuring the nodePort for the kubernetes service is an option which helps standardise the ports in use, as opposed to a random port being issued every time. However, the worker-names are still hard-coded and thats where the problem is.

Comment: Yes. You would need a script that updates the workers and reloads HAProxy every time a server gets added. This is a common problem.

Comment: I know that I am really late to this conversation... but if you use something like Ansible to configure your k8s cluster then when adding a new server to mix, Ansible could also update HApoxy config.